# Implement increment operation for different basis

Tags: python, list, addition

I am trying to implement increment operation to the list of integers such that

1. Length of the list is N
2. Each element is integers less than B. B is the base of the operation.
3. If I call the operation, it adds 1 to the last element of the list.
4. If it exceeds B, it carry up to next element.

For example, if the list is given as below with B = 13

```
list = [0, 0, 0, 5, 12]
increment(list)
print(list) # return [0, 0, 0, 6, 0]
```

My actual goal is to print all list from [0,0,0,0,0] to [12,12,12,12,12]. Yet I am having difficulty with carrying up numbers.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Code example

**Code**

```
def increment(lst, base):
  if len(lst) == 0:
    return lst

  lst[-1] += 1  # increment right most digit in list

  if lst[-1] >= base:
    # carry forward
    lst[-1] = 0   # reset right most to zero
                  # (1) increment without right most t
                  # (2) then append right most digit
    lst = increment(lst[:-1], base) + lst[-1:]

  return lst
```

**Test**

```
print('Base 12 example')
lst = [0, 0, 0, 5, 12]
print(lst)
for i in range(10):
  lst = increment(lst, 12)
  print(lst)

print('Base 3 example')
lst = [0, 0, 0]
print(lst)
for i in range(10):
  lst = increment(lst, 3)
  print(lst)
```

**Out**

```
Base 12 example
[0, 0, 0, 5, 12]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 6, 9]
Base 3 example
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
```